# Share Bluetooth tethered internet connection to Hyper-V

Tags: wireless-networking, android, bluetooth, tethering

I have an Android Device connected to a Wi-fi network, which is also sharing this connection to my notebook (Windows 10). I want to share it to my Hyper-V virtual machines too, but i can't find the Bluetooth Network Adapter on the Virtual Switch Manager.

Important: my notebook doesn't connect to the Wi-fi network, there's an issue present in the company's network, which i can't fix.

[image]

Is there any form to achieve this?

Comment: It seems sharing Bluetooth is not possible: [source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bdc4e7db-9260-48f9-a8aa-667ecc395421/hyperv-how-to-use-hosts-bluetooth-network-connection-on-a-vm?forum=winserverhyperv)